# Force initial React state when clicking the browsers history back button?

Tags: reactjs, browser-history, react-routing

Is there a way to force the **initial state** on a page (in a component) when the page was reached via the browsers **"history back"** button ?

#### Simplest Example:

- load this html file below
- change the state
- load a different website
- click the browsers "history back" button

Now I'd like my page to have it's initial state, not the changed state.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Try state</title></head>
<body>
    <script>
        // (You can check window.state in the DEV console)
        window.state = 'initial state';
    </script>
    <p id="state-display">static content</p>
    <button onclick="state = 'changed state'; document.getElementById('state-display').innerHTML = state;">change state</button>
</body>
</html>
```

#### More specifically

I am changing pages by calling `window.location.href = url`, and at the same time
I set a React state which results in displaying a `loading ...` info until
the new url is loaded.

I would expect, when clicking "back", that the previous page would be loaded
with its initial state again, but apparently the browser loads the
last state that it has seen when the page was left ?

E.g.

- page **A** is displayed,
- the user clicks on a go-to-page-**B** button,
- I'm setting a state to `isLoading` and call `window.location.href = pageB`,
- now when the user is on page **B** and clicks on the "back" button
  of the browser, page **A** is displayed again, but the state is `isLoading`
  again instead of the expected initial state, which it would be when visiting
  page **A** via a link or the address bar.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

// -- just some test state
const getNextState = (function(){
    const values = [ 'cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'bird', 'kangaroo' ];
    let index = 0;
    return function(){
        const current = index;
        index = index < values.length - 1 ? index + 1 : 0;
        return values[ current ];
    };
})();

// --
function App() {
    const [ state, setState ] = React.useState(() => getNextState() );

    // --
    // can't set state here, because `useEffect` hook is
    // not (always) called when clicking on "back" button
    // --
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mounted');
    }, []);

    // -- set state and change url
    const goToPage = function( page ){
        setState( '...loading' );
        window.location.href = page;
    };

    return <div>
        <h1>{ window.location.search === '?page2' ? 'Page 2' : 'Page 1' }</h1>
        <p>{ state }</p>
        <button onClick={ () => { goToPage('/?page1'); } }>go to page 1</button>
        <button onClick={ () => { goToPage('/?page2'); } }>go to page 2</button>
        <button onClick={ () => { setState( getNextState() ); } }>change state</button>
    </div>;
}

// --
const root = createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root')!
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

***Note 1):*** This apparently only happens in a production build (e.g. `yarn build`, `yarn start`).

***Note 2):*** Chrome and Firefox seem to behave in the same way here,
but this is a simplified example, and in my real app, where I use [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) and [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/), this problem is only reliably reproducible in Chrome.

***Note 3):*** I'm open for suggestions to change my routing,
but note that in some cases I have [statically pre-rendered](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation) pages
and need to do a redirect in a [`middleware.ts`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware), so I can't just use [client side routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects).

#### Approaches that apparently don't work:

Apparently no hooks (like [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)) are executed when clicking on "history back".
Not even the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event is fired.

#### UPDATE:

Apparently this behavior is not consistent. Right now Chrome doesn't show this problem anymore at my computer. Firefox still does.

Comment: Maybe use redux for the same ? I mean store the initial data you need in redux and access the same when browser back button is clicked.

Comment: I am using Redux in my actual code, as stated in *Note 2)*, which shows the same behavior. How would I detect "when browser back button is clicked" ?

Comment: You will have to store the value to localstorage and check this in useEffect

Comment: `useEffect` is not called when using "history back" (as stated im my code).